# RecyclerView Returning 'true' instead of JSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

My RecyclerView is returning the Boolean value 'true' for some odd reason.

I can't seem to fix the issue

[This is the output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWe0F.png)

It should display text from the JSON

JSON LINK - https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=cnn&apiKey=c80ddd850a524fe5975cad881d6f4aba

I am accessing the 'articles' JSON array and I want to display the title

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
MyAdapter mViewAdapter;

List<News> news_list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    new ParseNewsJSON().execute();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    mViewAdapter = new MyAdapter(new ArrayList<News>());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mViewAdapter);

}


public class ParseNewsJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private final String JSON_URL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=cnn&apiKey=c80ddd850a524fe5975cad881d6f4aba";

    String result = "";

    ArrayList<String> article_heading = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(JSON_URL);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {

                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                News news = new News();

                news.setHeading(String.valueOf(article_heading.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("title"))));

                // article_heading.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("title"));


                Log.d("news_JSON", article_heading.toString());

                Log.d("news", news.getHeading().toString());
                news_list.add(news);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mViewAdapter = new MyAdapter(news_list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mViewAdapter);
        mViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
}
```

MyAdapter Code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<News> newsArticleList;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView title;

    //description, genre;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_articleHeading);
//            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_description);
//            image = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    }
}

public MyAdapter (List<News> newsArticleList){

    this.newsArticleList = newsArticleList;
}
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_main, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    News news = newsArticleList.get(position);


    holder.title.setText(news.getHeading());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newsArticleList.size();
}
}
```

News.Java;

```
public class News {

private String heading;
//private String descrpiton;
private String img;


public String getHeading() {
    return heading;
}

public void setHeading(String heading) {
    this.heading = heading;
}

public String getImg() {
    return img;
}

public void setImg(String img) {
    this.img = img;
}
}
```

Comment: change this line JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result); to this JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
news.setHeading(String.valueOf(article_heading.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("title"))));
```

article_heading is an ArrayList, the method add returns a boolean to whether the list has changed due to your call or not.

You are not adding the title, you are adding the return of the ArrayList method, what you need is to change that line to that

```
String title = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("title");
article_heading.add(title);
news.setHeading(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your onPostExecute as below

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                News news = new News();

                String headingFromJson  =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
                article_heading.add(headingFromJson);
                news.setHeading(headingFromJson);

                // article_heading.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("title"));


                Log.d("news_JSON", article_heading.toString());

                Log.d("news", news.getHeading().toString());
                news_list.add(news);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mViewAdapter = new MyAdapter(news_list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mViewAdapter);
        mViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the heading of the news in a wrong way.

You should be doing the following in your Aynctask:

```
news.setHeading(jsonArray.getJsonObject(i).getString("title"));
```

You are instead putting the title inside the arraylist using add method. And putting the result of the add method as the heading. Add method of arraylist returns a boolean value indicating if the addition to list was successful or not. Thus you keep getting true instead of the actual text

Comment: You can also use the optString method instead of the getString i chose, it will basically return an empty string instead of throwing an exception if the title field is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In yout ParseNewsJSON class `onpostexecute()`

Change to :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                News news = new News();
                news.setHeading(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("title"));
                news_list.add(news);

    }
```

Instead of:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            News news = new News();

            news.setHeading(String.valueOf(article_heading.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("title"))));

            // article_heading.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("title"));


            Log.d("news_JSON", article_heading.toString());

            Log.d("news", news.getHeading().toString());
            news_list.add(news);

   }
```